# Dart - Read Keys and Values from a Map inside a Map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a variable with the following structure:

```
final Map<String, Map<double, String>> ingredients;
```

I need to access, as string, the "inner" map keys and values after indexing the external map:

```
ingredients.keys.elementAt(index)
```

The above code returns a "regular string", but when accessing the "inner" map:

```
ingredients.values.elementAt(index).keys
```

The result prints with round brackets around it. I suppose it occurs because the first example returns a string and the second returns an Itarable. But how do I make it a string without the round brackets?

.toString() does not work.

I can't make it a single Map<String, String> because I need the double value separated from the second string (a unit specification).

I will put the result inside a Flutter Text() widget inside a ListView.builder(), that is the reason of the indexing.

Resuming: I am getting (200)(g) and I need 200g.

Thanks for the attention. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "But how do I make it a string without the round brackets?" Can you provide an example of the exact output you're looking for?  That is, given a `Map<double, String>` with values `{1.0, 'some string'}`, what string representation do you want?

Comment: @jamesdlin Sure. I am getting (200)(g) and I need 200g as string output.

Comment: Can the inner `Map` actually contain multiple key-value pairs?  If not, it'd be simpler to define your own class (e.g. `class Quantity { double amount; String units; Quantity(this.amount, this.units); String toString() => '$amount$units'; }`).

Comment: I see, the inner map just haver a pair. I'll try to implement your Idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
var _value = ingredients.values.elementAt(index).values;
print(_value.substring(1,_value.length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a pretty solution but you can try:  `ingredients.values.elementAt(index).keys.toString().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\(\)]'),'');`

which will remove the parentheses anywhere in the keys.

I ran into the same problem as you did.

Hope this helps!